# Keeping WCF session alive from MVC Web API using cordova/phonegap

Tags: c#, wcf, cordova, session, asp.net-web-api

I want to keep a session alive, with a WCF consumed by a MVC4 Web API project (Both are on the same IIS), for every user using cordova/phonegap native apps, using ajax to communicate with the Web API. (No razor and no mvc helpers, that is)

I see this is properly not possible out if the box, since i'm using the HTTP protocol, which is stateless.

The reason I need this session, is that the backend code behind the WCF with a WSBinding is requiring a session. E.g. a user logs on with a username a password. Session is created. Now when the app calls the the Web API controller again, another method should be called getCurrentUsersData() without parameters, as the WCF design is made such that you are already logged in, thus the service using the session, knows who it is.

I see three ways of handling this:

1. Get the session id from the session by an ajax call upon login and keep it in the app (HTML5 Web storage?), and provide it at all the next calls. In c# I guess you can get the session back if you know the session id.
2. Have a database with a table associated to the MVC backend solution. The database could have usernames and passwords and a token, which is the one the frontend could remember. Then on each request, the MVC backend could log on to the server and make a new session before asking e.g. getCurrentUsersData() - The only trouble i have is that I need to store the passwords encrypted, not hashed and salted, which I believe is the best way, when openId is not an option. Another worry is the constant new sessions that would be made..
3. Use something I do not know much about, but it seems like some are using:  `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]` to associate the asp.net session with the WCF session. This might help me.

Any advise anyone?